# How do I get text to display over a graphic?

Tags: java

I'm new to Java so thank you for your time and help!

Basically I want to get text to display over a graphic I have created. Basically I made a trophy and want it to display "#1" on it.

Can anyone please help me with how to do this? Thank you again

Below is the code I have written so far. You can see that the position for the "#1" is all set and done but it's appearing behind the graphic.

```
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import java.awt.*; 
import java.net.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

public class BusinessCard extends JApplet
{

    /**
     * Paint method for applet.
     * 
     * @param  g   the Graphics object for this applet
     */
    public void paint(Graphics page)
    {
        //Variables used in rectangle
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int width = 500;
        int height = 300;



        page.drawRect(x, y, width, height);  //draws the rectangle using variables

        //Displays name
        Font f = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 26);
        page.setFont(f);
        page.drawString ("anonymous", 300,100);

        //Displays company
        Font g = new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 18);
        page.setFont(g);
        page.drawString ("blank", 320, 120);

        //Displays email
        Font h = new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 15);
        page.setFont(h);
        page.drawString ("email", 315,140);

        //int for the logo
        final int MID = 350;
        final int TOP = 168;

        setBackground (Color.yellow);  //Revisit. For some reason it only turns yellow                   after you resize the window

        Font i = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 16);
        page.setFont(i);
        page.drawString ("#1", MID+20, TOP+20);

        page.setColor (Color.orange);
        page.fillOval (MID, TOP, 60, 60); //bottom half of the trophy. the rounded part.
        page.drawArc (MID-8, TOP+15, 25, 25, 100, 160); //left arc
        page.drawArc (MID+43, TOP+15 , 25, 25, 280, 160); //right arc
        page.fillRect (MID+1, TOP+1, 59, 25); //make the top of the trophy flat basically
        page.fillRect (MID+22, TOP+60, 15, 25); //neck of the trophy
        page.drawLine (MID+48, TOP+84, MID+10, TOP+84); //base of the trophy


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to draw the trophy first and then write the text!

Whatever you draw appears on the top layer of the control.

Comment: I tried this method but the trophy will still appear over the text.

Answer (score 1):

First, do what sabre_raider said. You do want it before, but something else must be fixed too

You're drawing orange on orange. You draw the trophy, then set the background of your page to be yellow, then draw the "#1" in orange again. Change `setBackground` to `page.setColor` to draw in yellow (which appears to be what you want). setBackground sets the background of the applet, which im assuming is not what you want, but rather to draw the "#1" in yellow. If you did mean to set the background, make sure to do that in `Applet`'s `init` method!! Not each time you repaint. (Along with that, in init, have setSize(500, 300) to properly size the window to the size of your message)

Also, I recomend splitting that up into different methods, as that will just make it more readable. Here's what your methods should look like in general:

```
/**
 * Paint method for applet.
 * 
 * @param g
 *            the Graphics object for this applet
 */
public void paint(Graphics page)
{
    drawBorder( page );
    drawText( page );
    drawTrophy( page, 1 );
}

private void drawBorder(Graphics page) {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int width = 500;
    int height = 300;

    page.setColor( Color.black );
    page.drawRect( x, y, width, height );
}

private void drawText(Graphics page) {
    // Displays name
    Font f = new Font( "Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 26 );
    page.setFont( f );
    page.drawString( "anonymous", 300, 100 );

    // Displays company
    Font g = new Font( "Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 18 );
    page.setFont( g );
    page.drawString( "blank", 320, 120 );

    // Displays email
    Font h = new Font( "Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 15 );
    page.setFont( h );
    page.drawString( "email", 315, 140 );
}

private void drawTrophy(Graphics page, int number) {
    final int MID = 350;
    final int TOP = 168;
    page.setColor( Color.orange );
    page.fillOval( MID, TOP, 60, 60 ); // bottom half of the trophy. the rounded part.
    page.drawArc( MID - 8, TOP + 15, 25, 25, 100, 160 ); // left arc
    page.drawArc( MID + 43, TOP + 15, 25, 25, 280, 160 ); // right arc
    page.fillRect( MID + 1, TOP + 1, 59, 25 ); // make the top of the trophy flat basically
    page.fillRect( MID + 22, TOP + 60, 15, 25 ); // neck of the trophy
    page.drawLine( MID + 48, TOP + 84, MID + 10, TOP + 84 ); // base of the trophy

    Font i = new Font( "Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 16 );
    page.setColor( Color.yellow );
    page.setFont( i );
    page.drawString( "#" + number, MID + 20, TOP + 20 );
}
```

Comment: Oh I'm sorry ignore the yellow. That part was me experimenting around with something else and I removed it already. Edit" I figured it out! Thank you sabre and Alex! Basically I had to put the coding for the "#1" after the graphics coding. But I also had to switch the "#1" to a visible color.

Thanks for your help all!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I wouldn't paint directly onto a top level container.  I'd use something like a `JPanel` to do my custom painting and then add that to the top level container.

Secondly, you should avoid overriding `paint` where possible.  If you use a custom component as suggested in the first point, you should use `paintComponent` instead.

Thirdly, ALWAYS call `super.paint` (or `super.paintComponent` if you're using a custom component).

Fourthly, ever body else is right. You should be trying to draw you text AFTER the graphics...

This is the code I used:

```
public class BusinessCard extends JApplet {

    /**
     * Paint method for applet.
     *
     * @param g the Graphics object for this applet
     */
    public void paint(Graphics page) {

        super.paint(page);

        //Variables used in rectangle
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int width = 500;
        int height = 300;



        page.drawRect(x, y, width, height);  //draws the rectangle using variables

        //int for the logo
        final int MID = 350;
        final int TOP = 168;

        page.setColor(Color.orange);
        page.fillOval(MID, TOP, 60, 60); //bottom half of the trophy. the rounded part.
        page.drawArc(MID - 8, TOP + 15, 25, 25, 100, 160); //left arc
        page.drawArc(MID + 43, TOP + 15, 25, 25, 280, 160); //right arc
        page.fillRect(MID + 1, TOP + 1, 59, 25); //make the top of the trophy flat basically
        page.fillRect(MID + 22, TOP + 60, 15, 25); //neck of the trophy
        page.drawLine(MID + 48, TOP + 84, MID + 10, TOP + 84); //base of the trophy

        page.setColor(Color.yellow);  //Revisit. For some reason it only turns yellow                   after you resize the window

        Font font = UIManager.getFont("Label.font");

        page.setFont(font.deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 16));
        page.drawString("#1", MID + 20, TOP + 20);

        //Displays name
        page.setFont(font.deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 26));
        page.drawString("anonymous", 300, 100);

        //Displays company
        page.setFont(font.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 18));
        page.drawString("blank", 320, 120);

        //Displays email
        page.setFont(font.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 15));
        page.drawString("email", 315, 140);


    }
}
```

And it produced

[image]

Beware, that everybody may have the font you're trying to use installed (you code caused the applet to crash)

Comment: That image isn't what he wanted; he wanted a "#1" on top of the trophy; also, questioned already resolved (see comment on mine)

Comment: @AlexColeman Firstly, thanks for the update, I was focusing on everything else that was wrong and missed that point. Secondly, that's incredibly arrogant (*questioned already resolved (see comment on mine)*). Thirdly, my additional comments stand. Fourthly, I'm not chasing an accept, credit to you, I'm chasing solving the OP's over all problems...

Comment: Didn't mean my answer was right by that, he just commented on mine saying he basically resolved it himself :) And yeah, that's fine, was just pointing that out, didn't mean to offend you

Comment: @AlexColeman No worries, none-taken.  You post answered the question, I was just wary that there some things missing that help in the future ;)